# In MongoDB C# how to get nested array to perform aggregation query on it

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongo database with two collections: **Tournament** and **Player**.
A tournament contains, apart from simple attributes like `_id` and `Name`, a list of **Match** objects.

I have a query, in which I want to find the player with the most matches won. Before, I also had a collection **Match** in which all matches were contained. However I wanted to use the nested documents feature of MongoDB so I put those matches in **Tournament** instead.

The query before (one that worked):

```cs
var players = _matchCollection
    .Unwind<Match, Match>(m => m.WinnerId)
    .Group(m => m.WinnerId, g => new
    {
        Id = g.First().WinnerId,
        MatchesWon = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Now, my attempts so far (gives no error, but the players sequence contains no objects):

```cs
var players = _tournamentCollection.Aggregate().Unwind<Tournament,Match>(tour => tour.Matches)
    .Unwind<Match, Match>(m => m.WinnerId)
    .Group(m => m.WinnerId, g => new
    {
        Id = g.First().WinnerId,
        MatchesWon = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

So my question is: **how can I make such a query work on the nested array of matches?**

***EDIT***: Added the relevant classes.

**Tournament**:

```cs
public class Tournament
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surface { get; set; }
    public int? DrawSize { get; set; }
    public string? Level { get; set; }
    public string? Date { get; set; }
    public List<Match> Matches { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**Match**:

```cs
public class Match
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? MatchNum { get; set; }
    public string? WinnerId { get; set; }
    public string? LoserId { get; set; }
    public string? Score { get; set; }
    public string? BestOf { get; set; }
    public string? Round { get; set; }
    public string? TourneyId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think providing a sample document / the complete classes for `Tournament` to the question will be helpful.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks for the feedback, I edited my post to add the relevant classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to these 2 `$unwind` stages. This would return an empty value as `matches` is a 1-level array, and `winnerId` is not an array but it is a `string` field.

```cs
.Unwind<Tournament,Match>(tour => tour.Matches)
.Unwind<Match, Match>(m => m.WinnerId)
```

---

Instead, you need to these steps:

1. Create a `UnwindTournament` class that flattens the `Matches` list.
2. Unwind from the `Tournament` document to the `UnwindTournament` document.
3. Group by `Matches.WinnerId` field.
4. Take grouped `Key` as Id.

```cs
public class UnwindTournament
{
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surface { get; set; }
    public int? DrawSize { get; set; }
    public string? Level { get; set; }
    public string? Date { get; set; }
    public Match Matches { get; set; } = new Match();
}
```

```cs
var players = _tournamentCollection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<Tournament, UnwindTournament>(tour => tour.Matches)
    .Group(m => m.Matches.WinnerId, g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        MatchesWon = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

> Test Data

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63685837e5453d791ed775f4"
  },
  "name": "Tournament FIFA",
  "matches": [
    {
      "winnerId": "1",
      "loserId": "2"
    },
    {
      "winnerId": "3",
      "loserId": "4"
    },
    {
      "winnerId": "1",
      "loserId": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Demo & Result

[image]